# spark path configurations do not work properly on Windows

Tags: windows, apache-spark

So, I wanted to give an extra class path of jar files for Spark running on Windows.For that purpose, I added the following two lines in my `spark-defaults.conf` file. For linux, the additions work fine, but not for Windows. Any idea why?

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath   C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\extrajars\*
```

I also tried this, but still no luck.

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath   "C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\extrajars\*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using \\ instead of \

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath   C:\\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\\extrajars\\*
```

Start spark-shell and test:

```
scala> spark.conf.getAll.mkString("\n")
```

Should have

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath -> C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\extrajars\*
```

Hope, this helps!